# G Suite: Multiple shared inboxes for groups or aliases for groups?

Tags: google-groups, google-workspace-for-business

I'm working on setting up my company on G Suite and are currently working on migrating all our existing mailboxes.

I know that private mail accounts is coupled together with the users, which is fine.

And for shared inboxes (should as support, contact, etc.) I use *Groups for Business*.

I've two related questions regarding the Groups setup.
First, can I add an `mail alias` to the group?
I've a group called "Inbox" which has the email `hello@business.com` but I would also like to setup an alias for `hi@business.com` so that go into same group/inbox.

Secondly, and this is perhaps very much the same question but can I add multiple email address (not aliases) for an group? So I've **one** collaborate inbox which receives emails / posts from outsiders from both `support@business.com`, `contact@business.com` and so on?
The main difference from aliases is, that I can reply from each of the emails.

Essentially, all the shared inboxes would require quite a lot of groups but if this is the only way, so be it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add aliases to email IDs in groups. Check out this help doc to find out how exactly you can go about it: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2727156?hl=en

I'm guessing once you add email aliases, more customers are going to be able to reach you. But in *Groups For Business*, the chances of your team missing out on an important email are quite high, given that it's hard to assign emails, find out who is doing what, and track the status of emails on the platform.

You could try out [Hiver](https://hiverhq.com/?utm_source=StackExchange&utm_medium=Organic&utm_campaign=Shared%20Inboxes) - an email collaboration platform that works on top of Gmail. Your teams can basically manage all shared inboxes right from their personal Gmail accounts, collaborate on incoming emails seamlessly, and ensure that no email slips through the cracks.

With Hiver, you can delegate emails to team members in a click (without forwards and CCs), track their status, and also monitor performance of each member through key metrics such as average response time, and no. of emails closed, and more.

On top of that, your teammates can communicate with each other through notes, without sending internal emails, and also work together on customer replies (edit and comment) in real-time.

You also have the option of adding email aliases for your shared inboxes, on Hiver.

[image]